# How to resolve pyaws Missing parameter problem?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I am using [pyAWS](http://pyaws.sourceforge.net/index.html) wrapper for Amazon Web services. I want to show amazon search results on my web sites. For search I am using following codes.

```
from pyaws import ecs
ecs.setLicenseKey('Your-AWS-License-Key')
books = ecs.ItemSearch('python', SearchIndex='Books')
```

But it gives an error:
`u'ingParameter`'